# Derivative of n x n Invertible Matrix

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives

For an invertible $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$, define $f(A):=A^{-2}$. Calculate the derivative $D\space f(A)$. (i.e. give $D\space f(A)B$ for arbitrary $B$.)

I'm not super sure how to go about this?

Comment: You can find the derivative of the maps $A\mapsto A^2$ and $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ and use the chain rule. (For the second one, use a formula for $X^{-1}$ as a series, whenever this makes sense). The things you get are similar to the real case.

Answer (score 1):

In general, to find the derivative $Df(A)(H)$ you need to write $f(A+H)-f(A)=L(H)+O(\Vert H\Vert^\alpha)$, where $L(H)$ is linear on $H$, and $\alpha>1$.

Let's do this with $g(A)=A^{-1}$: For all $H$ sufficiently small, $A-H$ in invertible, and
$$(A-H)^{-1}=A^{-1}(1-HA^{-1})^{-1}=A^{-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(HA^{-1})^n=A^{-1}+A^{-1}HA^{-1}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(HA^{-1})^n$$
so $(A+H)^{-1}-A^{-1}=-A^{-1}HA^{-1}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-HA^{-1})^n$. The first term in the RHS is linear on $H$ and the second one has norm of order $O(\Vert H\Vert^2)$, so this indicates that $Dg(A)(H)=-A^{-1}HA^{-1}$.

Now, you have to *prove* that
$$\lim_{H\to 0}\frac{g(A+H)-g(A)+A^{-1}HA^{-1}}{\Vert H\Vert}=0$$
(use the formulas above), from which you conclude that indeed $Dg(A)(H)=-A^{-1}HA^{-1}$.

Consider then $k(A)=A^2$, and find its derivative in a similar manner (it will be easier in fact). Then use the chain rule: $Df(A)(H)=D(g\circ k)(A)(H)=Dg(k(A))Dk(A)(H)$

Answer (score 0):

The map: $\Phi(A) = A^{-1}$ is differentiable over $GL_n$ and $D\Phi(A) H = - A^{-1} H A^{-1}$ for all $A \in GL_n$ and all $H \in M_{n \times n}$.

Letting $B(M,N) = MN$, $B$ is bilinear map on a finite dimensional normed vector space, hence continuous and so differentiable with $DB(M,N)(H,K) = HN + MK$.

Now $f = B \circ (\Phi, \Phi)$, so:

$$Df(A) H = DB(\Phi(A), \Phi(A)) (D\Phi(A)H, D\Phi(A) H) = DB(A^{-1}, A^{-1})( -A^{-1} H A^{-1} , -A^{-1} HA^{-1}) = -A^{-1} (HA^{-1} + A^{-1}H) A^{-1}$$